# Isn't reflex angle between $180^\circ$ and $360^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving this question.

> Given that $\sin\theta = 5/13 $, find $\theta$, $\cos\theta$, and $\tan\theta$ where $\theta$
>
> (a) is an acute angle, and
>
> (b) is a reflex angle.

I could get the acute angle which is $22.62^\circ$. So, I did $360^\circ - 22.62^\circ$, to get the reflex angle, but the answer is  $157.38^\circ$ which is $180^\circ - 22.62^\circ$. Why is that? Do I have a wrong understanding of a reflex angle? Please help.

Comment: We were given that $\sin(135)$. What does that mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean given that $\sin(135)$?  Did you mean $\cos\theta$? $\tan\theta$?  where $\theta$ is an acute angle? where $\theta$ is a reflex angle? Please clarify.  There is clearly missing information.

Comment: sine is positive so thats gotta be in Quadrant II

Comment: Your edit still does not make sense.  Did you mean $\sin\theta = 5/13$?  Also, you have not addressed the other questions I raised.

Comment: My apology it is sin(5/13)

Comment: You should have $\sin\theta = 5/13$, $\cos\theta$, and $\tan\theta$.  Sine, cosine, and tangent are functions which take angles as arguments.

Comment: cos and tan is the radian.

Comment: Sorry, Martin, you're not making sense. "cos and tan is the radian" is a word salad, not a comprehensible mathematical statement.

Comment: In any event, it seems to me that not Martin but whoever put the question together is confused about reflex angles.

Comment: If $\theta$ is supposed to be in radians, then $\theta = \arcsin(5/13) \approx 0.3947911197$.

Comment: The answer is (a) θ = 22.62°, cosθ = 0.923, tanθ = 0.417   (b) θ = 157.38°, cosθ = -0.923, tanθ = 0.417. Does this make more sence?

Comment: In that case, I agree with Gerry Myerson.  The answers to part (b) do not agree with the definition of reflex angle, which you have correctly understood.

Comment: Writing $\sin=\frac{5}{13}$ is a bad thing to do. It's like writing $\sqrt\,=4$, or $+=11$. Remember "$\sin$" written by itself is just a sin.

Comment: Thank you. Is the answer giving the reflection by doing 180-22.62?

Comment: What do you mean $\sin = \frac 5{13}$?  The sine of *what* is $\frac 5{13}$.  What do you mean find $\theta$?  What is $\theta$? It could be anything.  What do you mean find $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$?  What is $\theta$?  What do you mean if (a) is acute?  What is (a)?  What do you mean if (b) is reflexive?  What is (b)?  You question is not clearly written.

Comment: The answers given for part (b) would make sense if the word *reflex* were replaced by the word *obtuse*.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are trying to ask is the following:

> Given that $\sin\theta=\frac{5}{13}$ find $\theta$, $\cos\theta$, and $\tan\theta$, where **(a)** $\theta$ is an acute angle, and **(b)** $\theta$ is a reflex angle.

I've just looked up reflex angle, and the definition says that $\theta$ is a reflex angle iff $180^{\circ}<\theta<360^{\circ}$. It follows that if $\theta$ is a reflex angle, then $\sin\theta<0$, so there is no solution if $\theta$ is a reflex angle.

If $\theta$ is acute than $\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)\approx22.6^{\circ}$.

Also, if $\theta$ is acute then $\cos\theta>0$ and $\tan\theta>0$. From the fact that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, you get that $\cos\theta=\frac{12}{13}$, which gives you that $\tan\theta=\frac{5}{12}$.

Answer (score -1):

But $\sin (360 - \theta) \ne \sin\theta$.

so you can not figure that if $\sin \theta=\frac 5{13};0\le \theta < 360^{\circ}$, that that would mean the reflexive angle $\psi = 360-\theta$ will have $\sin \psi = \sin \theta$.  In fact just the opposite;  $\sin \psi = -\sin \theta$.

So:

$\sin \theta = \frac 5{13}$.

Find $\theta$:  $\frac 5{13}>$ so $0< \theta < 180$.  So if a) $\theta$ is accute then $\theta = \arcsin \frac 5{13}$.  If b) $\theta$ is reflexive this is not possible and there is no solution.

$\cos \theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} = \pm\frac {12}{13}$.  So if a) $\theta$ is accute  then $\cos \theta \ge 0$ and $\cos \theta = \frac {12}{13}$.  If b) then $\theta$ is impossible so there is no solution.

$\tan \theta = \frac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$.  So if a) $\theta$ is accute then $\tan \theta = \frac {\frac 5{13}}{\frac {12}{13}} = \frac 5{13}$ and, again, for (b) there is no solution.

Now it's not sure if I'm supposed to leave it as $\theta = \arcsin \frac {5}{13}$ or if I'm supposed to do some fancy geometry and trigonometry to find out what the angle of right triangle with sides of $5,12,13$ is.  But I'm not going to grub in the mud unless I know there's a potato down there.

I could punch keys into a calculator to find $\theta = \arcsin \frac {5}{13}$ but *nobody* wants some stupid decimal when $\arcsin \frac {5}{13}$ is much more descriptive than $\theta = 22.6whogivesapileoffetiddingokidneys1087668.....$

So $\theta = \arcsin \frac 5{13}=\arctan \frac 5{12}$.  Final answer.

.....

I suspect the person asking the question meant obtuse.

In which case b)  $90 < \theta < 180$ and as $\sin{180 - \theta}=\sin \theta$ we have $\theta = 180 -\arcsin \theta$.  And $\cos \theta < 0$ so $\cos \theta =-\frac 5{12}$ and $\tan \theta =-\frac 5{12}$.  By the way we can express $\theta = \arctan -\frac 5{12}$.

Comment: "Who gives a pile of fetid dingo kidneys"?? 